# Custom private street view style map

Tags: google-street-view

I moved across country to a very rural, hilly, property and would like to share the trails with my father who is 5000km away and limited to a wheelchair.

Is there any way to create a 'street view' style map that is private?

I would like him to be able to navigate his way around and explore from the comfort of his computer.   I would do one on street view but then it would be public and my wife has expressed misgivings of giving everyone a virtual map of our home and property.

Comment: I believe sites like mapbox.com and maptiler.com allow you to create private maps, meaning the general public wouldn't have access, though obviously the companies themselves would. You could use Google's Streetview API to download the images you need and then integrate them into something similar. I might be missing the point.

Comment: when you say "Streetview" do you mean panorama points on a map that someone can explore. Or do you mean just a normal Google Map, with your own custom markers? 
What experience do you have with mapping? QGIS, Python, JavaScript?